# Using existing tools, how can I extract into separate images the Luma, Cb, Cr channels of a JPEG image?

Tags: image-processing, jpeg

I am seeking a method to extract into separate images the Luma (Y), Cb (blue component), Cr (red component), channels of the JPEG images:

- [Seattle Police Department image #1](http://spdblotter.seattle.gov/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/vehicle-of-interest-1.mpg_000434496.jpg)
- [Seattle Police Department image #2](http://spdblotter.seattle.gov/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/vehicle-of-interest-3.mpg_001177303.jpg)
- [Seattle Police Department image #3](http://spdblotter.seattle.gov/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/vehicle-of-interes-2.mpg_000229395.jpg)

I would like results equivalent to this [example from Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Barns_grand_tetons_YCbCr_separation.jpg)

The output must be calculated **directly** from the JPEG Start-of-Scan (SOS) data and other data in the JPEG, **rather** than 'back calculated' from the RGB images output by a decompressor.  The purpose of this task is to produce images which represent the 'raw data' as closely as possible.

Are there existing tools which can accomplish this?  I am considering throwing together something using Python, PyImage, etc. but I am surprised my search for open source or free tools has come up empty.  I am aware there are many libraries which could help, although I am open to becoming aware of more libraries.

For this question, the correct answer would be a tool chain of free and/or open-source tools which can do the job.  Tools with source are preferred.  These tools can run on any platform, but Linux or Win32 would be immediately useful.

**Answer inspired by codelogic**

Given the libjpeg implementation, change djpeg.c and wrppm.c.

wrppm.c:

```
189:    case JCS_RGB:
190: +  case JCS_YCbCr:
191:    /* emit header for raw PPM format */
```

djpeg.c

```
560:   case FMT_PPM:
561: +   cinfo.quantize_colors = 0;
562: +   cinfo.out_color_space = JCS_YCbCr;
```

Obviously, this is quick hack, because I have a private copy where PPM output is always forced to YCbCr, but it works and I thank you, codelogic, for your Stone Code Logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested your best bet would be to use libjpeg directly. Specifically, you might be able to set `jpeg_decompress_struct`'s `out_color_space` member to be `JCS_YCbCr` instead of `JCS_RGB` and read the scanlines as usual. [Here's](http://parallel.vub.ac.be/~johan/MpegStills/jpeg2yuv.c) some sample code (GPL).

Comment: Thank you for leading me by the nose!  I made some one-liners to djpeg.c and wrppm.c which allow me to output YCbCr ppm files as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Well the obvious one is [libjpg](http://www.ijg.org/).

Comment: In fact, therein I found "jpegtran -grayscale" which is half the battle.  I just need to extract the Cr, Cb data, and of course I have the source for jpegtran.  I might accept this as answer if nothing which can do all 3 channels as-is turns up.