# Transmitting a large image incrementally via patches over a low bandwidth connection

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, jpeg

Scenario: Most smartphones have a high resolution camera that generates photos that may range up to 1-1.5 MB. Sending that over a low bandwidth connection like 2G would take a long time.

Is there an algorithm that can:

1. Create a highly compressed first-view (like a thumbnail, but the same size) and send that across, and
2. Create subsequent 'patches' of data that add to the first file?
3. The more 'patches' that are received, the higher the end-quality, until the original is completely reconstructed.

I'm looking for something that would work on jpeg images.

Comment: JPEG has already that built in. See progressive JPEG http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-11.html http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/0,,sid9_gci212835,00.html

Comment: Hi there EugeneO - I had a look at progressive jpegs earlier, but thanks for the links! As far as I understand it, its still part of the same 'connection' / stream. However, I'm looking for implementing the same concept, but as 'patch' files that are sent discretely after the first. Webservers will probably reject a partial upload of an progressive jpeg which is 1.5 MB big, but the chances of a 100 kb initial file being uploaded successfully are much higher.

Comment: I'm also exploring breaking the jpeg into Luma, Cb, Cr channels like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685739/using-existing-tools-how-can-i-extract-into-separate-images-the-luma-cb-cr-ch and then piecing it back together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any progressive image compression for such requirements. JPEG 2000 has a good progressive encoding. You can even specify progressive transmission count. So, you can implicitly set patch size. If that's not enough for you, then you can use the other progressive wavelet image compression algorithms such as [EZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EZW), [SPIHT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPIHT) etc.

Comment: Hi there. I've been reading up on SPIHT and that seems very close to what I need. But it seems like it will need a lot of adaptation for it to work with jpegs (their algorithm works with RAW files) and for it to output progressive quality 'patches' which I was thinking of. Do you have any other thoughts on how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: SPIHT and EZW like codecs are some research implementations. Most of research implementations have some serious limitations such as restricted to 2-power-of dimensions, only grayscale, only RAW images etc. So, unfortunately you need to cope their limitations on your own. Also, if you're familiar with wavelet algorithms, you can build your own progressive schema too. As you know, wavelet has several sub bands which stores some frequency ranges. And you can use a statistical model and a proper arithmetic coder to encode those sub bands. So, you can progressively transmit whole image.

Comment: Thanks Osman - could you help me understand what is 'progressive transmission count'? I wasnt able to find anything on the 'count' aspect.

Comment: I don't know exact term in here, so I've used "progressive transmission count". Actually, it's wavelet decomposition level and it approximately means number of patches in your term. Some image converters allow you to set it, while others simply use 5 as default.